# のように vs と同様 to show similarity

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

In my writing assignment, I wrote this paragraph.

テレワーク**のように**、オンライン授業もいい経験だと思う。パンデミックの前は毎日、通学しないといけないし、何度も乗り換えをしないといけないし、往復だと４時間以上、つまり一日の６分の１以上かかるのであり、私にとっては面倒くさくて疲れることばかりだった。

It was corrected to

テレワーク**と同様**、オンライン授業もいい経験だと思う。(I think と同じように would work too.)

Was there something wrong in the usage of のように to show likeness or similarity between telework and online class?

Comment: or was it just a matter of style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between のように and と同様 is lost in translation here.

Both can be translated to "like", but actually there is a difference:

> のように = "just as with"
>
> と同様　 = "just like"

Tell me which one sounds more logical:

> Online classes are a good experience, just like telecommuting (is).
>
> Online classes are a good experience, just as with telecommuting.

The second sentence is essentially what the のように in this sentence sounds like to a Japanese person. のように begs the question, "they're both [adj], in what way?" This unanswered question is why it will sound "vague" to a Japanese person. You are not trying to say that both are good in a certain way, you are just saying that both are good, so と同様 is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and it was somehow expected:

> 「テレワークのように」だと、不自然です。It sounds vague. 「テレワークがいい経験であるように、」なら、わかります。

It is interesting that a high-context language like Japanese would find something like this to be vague.

Comment: It's not really meaningful to describe an entire language as "high-context" just like it isn't really meaningful to judge a person's character based on his nationality. There will be things that are obvious in certain cultures that aren't in others. But this question has nothing to do with that, it's about the logical rigor of the sentence.